# royalty trusts in TurboTax

Tags: united-states, income-tax, turbotax

Trying to figure out how to get my taxes correct in TurboTax. I have owned shares in several royalty trusts. At the end of the year, they come out with tax information. Here is an example: http://s24.q4cdn.com/856292872/files/doc_downloads/tax_info/WHZ_OilTrustGeneric_Package2021.pdf

I imported the trades from my brokerage, and TurboTax created some fake "trades" on payout dates. But I'm not sure where to go from there.

EDIT: To get to the source of the file, either go to http://whzt.q4web.com/home/default.aspx, or google "Whiting USA trust 2" and go to the first hit. In either case, follow by going to "tax information".

Comment: Can you provide the link to the source of this file? A link to a random CDN is not secure and may contain malware.